# how to connect back end java code with front end code(Html and css and java script) while constructing web site?

Tags: java

Here my back-end code is on java and front end code is with html and css and java script, is there best way to pass my logic from back end to front end

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: javascript is one word, not two

Comment: If you search "Beginning web development with Java" I'm sure you will find a good tutorial. This question is too broad as it stands here.

Comment: Unfortunately there are lots of "best ways" to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use REST services. Your front end code can make a REST call to the back end and let it work its magic. It's a pretty standard approach in industry projects.

The people who have commented are right in saying that the question is a bit too broad, and the answer really depends on your use case, but here are some resources you can go look at to find out more:

https://www.genuitec.com/connecting-angular-2-app-java-ee-backend/
http://draptik.github.io/blog/2013/07/13/angularjs-example-using-a-java-restful-web-service/
https://dzone.com/articles/web-applications-frontend-and-backend-communicatio

Comment: Thanks those links helped me alot :)

Comment: @AlavalaMahesh No problem. Welcome to StackOverflow!